# How to add amazon-ecr-credential-helper to path

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to set up [amazon-ecr-credential-helper](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper) so that I can have an ansible script automatically push / pull to my aws ecr docker repository, but the instructions for installing it seem very vague.

Since I already have Docker installed I tried cloning the repo and running `make docker`. It says that outputs the binary "to local directory." Which appeared to be true, I ended up with `./bin/local/docker-credential-ecr-login` being built. So I tried adding that to my path:

`.bash_profile`
`export PATH="$HOME/anaconda3/bin:$HOME/projects/amazon-ecr-credential-helper/bin:$PATH"`

And restarting my terminal, but when I try to do a docker push I get the error `no basic auth credentials`.

And if I try to do a `docker-compose build` I get the error `Credentials store error: StoreError('docker-credential-ecr-login not installed or not available in PATH',)`.

Comment: Why not just move the binary to /usr/local/bin ? And did you update the  ~/.docker/config.json like the repo says?

Comment: @strongjz Yeah, I did update the docker config like the docs suggest. Tried moving the binary to `/usr/local/bin` and restarting, but that didn't make it any better. Appreciate the advice, but I think I'll just side-step the issue and do it manually or do it with Ansible a different way!

Comment: Received this error when upgrading to Mac OS High Sierra.  It seems to have deleted my ECR credentials helper from `/usr/bin` but kept the reference to it in `$HOME/.docker/config.json`  I just removed the reference to "ecr-login" in my `config.json` and everything works again!

Answer (score 3):

Steps to set up Credential helper on Ubuntu.

This assumes, you have docker installed and AWS credentials available at:       ~/.aws/credentials file

1. Clone the git repository https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper.git
2. cd  to the cloned folder "amazon-ecr-credential-helper"
3. run the command on terminal "make docker"
4. it will create the binary "./bin/local/docker-credential-ecr-login"
5. Copy this binary to /usr/bin/lib with the command " sudo cp ./bin/local/docker-credential-ecr-login /usr/bin/lib/docker-credential-ecr-login
6. Create or modify the docker config.json file available at /.docker/config.json with the below content

   ```
     {
         "credsStore": "ecr-login"
      }
   ```

   then try pushing the docker image to AWS ECR repository

Ravneet Arora(DevOps)

Comment: Any idea on how to do this on Windows 10?

Comment: For mint 5. sudo cp ./bin/local/docker-credential-ecr-login /usr/bin/docker-credential-ecr-login. Also 6 refers to your home dir

Comment: For Ubuntu, the destination path for cp would be /usr/bin/ or /usr/local/bin rather than /usr/bin/lib, right?